# How to render Select in Jsp for a list of Object

Tags: java, jsp, jstl

I have a list of Object containing issue number and issue name both belonging to separate table.

```
issue Number    issue name 
Rac12345         test User Cannot Login 
Rac345544        Logs are not printed
```

I am getting them in my Controller but in JSP i am not able to render it

my code in JSP

```
   <tr>
        <td>Issues:</td>
        <td><form:select path="issues" items="${unassignedIssueList}"
                var="c" itemValue="${c[0]}" itemLabel="${c[1]}" /></td>
        <td><form:errors path="issues" cssClass="error" /></td>
    </tr>
```

how do i render it?

Comment: Show the code creating the lists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by doing following

```
     <td>Issues:</td>
     <td><form:select path="issues">
          <c:forEach var="list" items="${unassignedIssueList}">
             <option value="${list[0]}">${list[1]}</option>
          </c:forEach>
     </form:select></td>
```